# How does one install a package in hatch?

Tags: python-3.x, hatch

Hatch seems amazing, uses pip rather than an in-house installer, and I want to use it.

However, I have searched through the internet and found many indications that `hatch` should come with an `install` command accessed via `hatch install`.  However, on `python3.10 @ hatch = 1.6.3`, there is no `install` command:

```
Usage: hatch [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

   _   _       _       _
  | | | |     | |     | |
  | |_| | __ _| |_ ___| |__
  |  _  |/ _` | __/ __| '_ \
  | | | | (_| | || (__| | | |
  \_| |_/\__,_|\__\___|_| |_|

Options:
  -e, --env TEXT                  The name of the environment to use [env var:
                                  `HATCH_ENV`]
  -p, --project TEXT              The name of the project to work on [env var:
                                  `HATCH_PROJECT`]
  --color / --no-color            Whether or not to display colored output
                                  (default is auto-detection) [env vars:
                                  `FORCE_COLOR`/`NO_COLOR`]
  --interactive / --no-interactive
                                  Whether or not to allow features like
                                  prompts and progress bars (default is auto-
                                  detection) [env var: `HATCH_INTERACTIVE`]
  -v, --verbose                   Increase verbosity (can be used additively)
                                  [env var: `HATCH_VERBOSE`]
  -q, --quiet                     Decrease verbosity (can be used additively)
                                  [env var: `HATCH_QUIET`]
  --data-dir TEXT                 The path to a custom directory used to
                                  persist data [env var: `HATCH_DATA_DIR`]
  --cache-dir TEXT                The path to a custom directory used to cache
                                  data [env var: `HATCH_CACHE_DIR`]
  --config TEXT                   The path to a custom config file to use [env
                                  var: `HATCH_CONFIG`]
  --version                       Show the version and exit.
  -h, --help                      Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  build    Build a project
  clean    Remove build artifacts
  config   Manage the config file
  dep      Manage environment dependencies
  env      Manage project environments
  new      Create or initialize a project
  project  View project information
  publish  Publish build artifacts
  run      Run commands within project environments
  shell    Enter a shell within a project's environment
  status   Show information about the current environment
  version  View or set a project's version
```

And the `dep` command:

```
Usage: hatch dep [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  hash  Output a hash of the currently defined dependencies
  show  Display dependencies in various formats
```

---

How does one add a dependency with hatch?  I'd like to make sure it is as competitive as `poetry`, which does provide an install option.

Alternatively: is there a newer version of hatch for newer versions of python3 that does have these installation features?

If that is the case, no problem -- I can work around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `hatch shell` or `hatch run`, Hatch will automatically spawn a new environment to run in and install your project into that environment for you. You don't need to manage doing anything like `pip install` or `hatch install` manually.

It looks like for now you'll need to hand-curate the dependencies.

Comment: hatch is great and I appreciate the hands off approach, just needed to rule it out to make sure I was getting it.  Online searches indicate that old versions of hatch did support dependency management.  `poetry` on the other hand, often staggers during dev with 7-15 min package dependency evaluations that pip steamrolls with its lighter weight (but sometimes wrong) dep solver.  The result is you wind up managing a `requirements` file w/ pip and a `poetry` `.toml` file, and hatch just says "OK, use pip".